# Is it possible to store Strings in Json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem that I have is, that I want to store data that I got in JavaScript into a JSON file.

For example the JSON file at the beginning looks like this:

```
{
    "ip": "none",
    "user": "none"
}
```

Now I have defined to JavaScript variables:

```
const ip = '127.0.0.1';
const user = 'me225hey';
```

I've already tried the following:

```
$.getJSON( "path/to/foo.json", function( data ) {
      data.ip = ip;
      data.user = user;
});
```

This way I could only retrieve the data but not store it. After searching in the internet I could only find a way to retrieve the data.

If it isn't possible to store data in a JSON file by JavaScript code. Where should I store my data otherwise? I can't use SQL for that. It should be locally and possible in Angular.

Comment: JavaScript can not write to a file from the browser. You need something on the server that can write to a file.

Comment: In angular, you have to create a service for that.

Comment: You can still store in cookie, local or session storage if you have to.

Comment: You can save in DATA, please see this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Just to add my 2c, there a variety of offline storage mechanisms, namely: localStorage, sessionStorage, indexedDB, cookies, Cache API. Have a look at this presentation for more info: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/11CJnf77N45qPFAhASwnfRNeEMJfR-E_x05v1Z6Rh5HA

Answer (score 0):

To store data you have several options,

1. Use a Service since you are using Angular
2. Store it on Local Storage / Session Storage etc... check image below

[image]

3. Or you can use Cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can't store it locally as a file, not with js at least. Either store it on a server, or check out local storage, or session storage to store it locally. But it wouldn't be stored as a file...and if someone clears their cache, it would be gone. So this would be only a temporary storage.

Look here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage